# Holding task for AlertDialog response

Tags: java, android, task, android-alertdialog, jsch

I wanted to hold a task for an AlertDialog response. I know UI interaction in the doInBackground method is against the rules, but there is no possibility to do it in onPreExecute.

```
 public static class AsyncMongoConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        try {
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "false");

            Session session = jSch.getSession("username", "host-address", 22);
            //session.setPassword("password");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            session.setPortForwardingL(27017, "host-address", 27017);

            MongoClient            mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Collections.singletonList(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("user", "authdb", "password".toCharArray())));
            FindIterable<Document> documents   = mongoClient.getDatabase("database").getCollection("users").find();
            Log.d("MongoClient", documents.iterator().next().toJson());

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I wanted to create a port forwarding from my local device to a remote host-address. But I want to enable StrictHostKeyChecking, because it's a big security issue, if I don't. My problem is now to implement an UserInfo for the session. I need to prompt the user a password, if I don't want to pre-save it. Also I wan't to create a dialog, that warns the user, if the fingerprint of the remote host is not known. In this case it isn't. In the implementation I wanted to use the promptPassword for implementation, BUT I can't wait for any response of the alert dialog, expect with a while-loop, which is really not efficient, I believe. The promptPassword method awaits, that I return a boolean.

```
public class SSHUserInfo implements UserInfo {

  private String  passphase = null;
  private String  password  = null;
  private Context context   = null;

  public SSHUserInfo(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassphrase() {
      return passphase;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
      return password;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean promptPassword(String s) {

      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean promptPassphrase(String s) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean promptYesNo(String s) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void showMessage(String s) {

  }
}
```

I already informed about implementing a respond awaiting AlertDialog, but it doesn't fit my purposes :( I

Thanks for your help!

Tarik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`Object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) and [`Object.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--)

```
@Override
public boolean promptPassword(String s) {

    synchronized (someObject) {
        // Notify GUI thread about password prompt
        publishProgress();

        // wait for password prompt to be submitted
        wait();
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)
{
     // Do password prompt here

     // And tell background thread, that we have a password already
     synchronized (someObject) {
         notify();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. I learned much about synchronization and waiting/notifying. But this case is not the best for mine, I found a workaround. Thank you!!!